# How can I create and fill in a form using drawstring in a jTextPane?

Tags: java

I'm getting into graphical stuff in Java and want to display text. As I've read, drawString() is the standard method for this. My code to draw the string is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDisplay extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("My Text", 10, 20);
    }
}
The class executing this is:

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextDisplay d = new TextDisplay();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(d);
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This produces a window with the text "My Text" in it as expected. The question now is: How can I draw any String? With this I have to write the String into the paint() method, but I want to input it from somewhere else as a variable.

This is the exact thing someone else submitted and the answers were not clear and understandable. Why can't I just use drawstring from within a servicing routine?

Comment: 1) This is not how to do custom painting. 2) See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do the painting and structure your class. 3) *How can I draw any String?* - use a `JLabel`. It has a `setText()` method. Why are you attempting to reinvent the wheel? In any case you would need your own "setter" method if you want to draw any string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use create a class variable inside the TextDisplay class that is accessiable from the paint method, and you can create a setText method to change the text:

```
public class TextDisplay extends JPanel{
    //Add a class variable that stores the text to paint
    String textToPaint = "Example";

    //Override the paintComponent method (Not paint)
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //Alawys call super to paint the parent component background/borders etc
        super.paintComponent(g);       

        // Draw your text
        g.drawString(textToPaint,10,20);
    }

    //Add a method to change the text
    public void setText(String text){
        //Change the class variable text
        textToPaint = text;

        //Repaint the JPanel to show the new text
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use the following in your main method or anywhere that has access to you TextDisplay component `d.setText("Your message here");`

Comment: (1-) it is the responsibility of all Swing components to determine their own preferred size to it will work with layout managers. The tutorial I linked to in my comment shows how this is done.  Also, because the length of text can change the component should be revalidated(). The location of the text should take into account that there might be a Border added to the component. In short there are so many things to consider for something this basic which is why my suggestion was to use a JLabel.

Comment: Fair comment, there is a lot to consider, but this answers the questionat hand. Like the tutorial you linked, OP needs to start somewhere, and a basic paintComponent method does the trick. They will run into the other cavets themselves as they try new things or read further into the tutorial.

Comment: People are lazy. If someone spoon feeds them the answer they tend not to read the tutorial.  The OP even stated in their question that: *This is the exact thing someone else submitted* - indicating they just copied the code without doing much investigation on their own.